# NativeCommandError executing python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, notepad++, indentation

When I execute this code I'm getting a native command error:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename)
        print(str(os.path.join(root, filename)))
```

I edited the code in Notepad++ and I have the Python indent plugin on. I've also ensured that the indentation is set to 4 spaces, instead of tab.

Comment: Don't make us guess what your error message says.

Comment: No need to guess - it is in the title. There isn't anything other than that returned (run from PowerShell) - + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
    print(str(os.path.join(root, filename)))

Comment: OK, so now we know you're running it from Powershell.  Does it behave differently if you run it directly from a command prompt (something like `python3 yourscript.py`) ?  You might at least get a better error report in that case.  BTW, if you pasted that excerpt exactly as it exists in your script then it's missing a closing parenthesis on the `matches.append` line.